# 'Re-Timing' my Engine after timing belt removal

Tags: engine, timing-belt, outback

I have little mechanical experience.

I decided to try and do the Timing Belt / Water Pump in my 2003 Subaru Outback ( Interference Engine ).

Watched a video where someone neglected to put the engine in time before removing the timing belt tensioner ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-elmEngTEE ).

I followed his direction took off my belt tensioner and I have also cranked the main shaft about a quarter turn, I realized that the cams weren't moving in sync and stopped.

Can someone tell me how to get my engine in time so I can install the new timing belt.

Comment: Welcome to the site. A quarter-turn on the crank is one-eighth on the camshaft. You *may* be able to get away with it by "rewinding" the work done so far (return the crank back to your best estimate of where it was prior to turning, install the belt and tensioner) and then proceed to line up the timing marks on the crankshaft and camshaft. I'll leave this as a comment since I can't vouch for the doability of this approach though. Perhaps one of the Subie guys can chime in.

Comment: I did as suggested. After 'undoing' the quarter turn on the crank, I installed the belt and turned the engine until the three hash marks should have been in position. The right cam needed about an eighth of a rotation so I removed the timing belt made the adjustment and she started right up and sounds good too!

Comment: Glad that all's well, enjoy your hard work! I suggest you post the steps you took as an answer (you can answer your own questions).

Answer (score 2):

The OP was fortunate to get away with it here. Note that this isn't guaranteed to work always, especially if the crank and cams are severely out of time on an interference engine.

---

[Me:](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22707/re-timing-my-engine-after-timing-belt-removal#comment33990_22707)

> A quarter-turn on the crank is one-eighth on the camshaft. You may be able to get away with it by "rewinding" the work done so far (return the crank back to your best estimate of where it was prior to turning, install the belt and tensioner) and then proceed to line up the timing marks on the crankshaft and camshaft.

[Calvin:](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22707/re-timing-my-engine-after-timing-belt-removal#comment34033_22707)

> I did as suggested. After 'undoing' the quarter turn on the crank, I installed the belt and turned the engine until the three hash marks should have been in position. The right cam needed about an eighth of a rotation so I removed the timing belt made the adjustment and she started right up and sounds good too!

Comment: Another one bites the dust.  Answered   :-)