# Replaced a ton of parts - grey/white/black exhaust smoke and funny noise persist

Tags: chevrolet, cylinder-head, corsa

I've replaced my Corsa Bakkie's cylinder head, changed plugs & oil, cleaned the petrol pump, replaced everything that I could.

There is still a funny noise (like the sound when you put a card at your bicycle's wheel) and sometimes the smoke is white/grey/black ...

Please assist, I have been spending a fortune on it so far and is sure that I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please give a full list of what you have replaced? Is the smoke always present? When is the smoke the most? Also, where is the funny noise coming from? Is it the engine bay, wheels or something else? The more details you provide, the better the chances of us helping you out.

Comment: Thanks Zaid. When the bakkie is idling there is a bit of smoke and obviously when you "ref" it it becomes more. The noise is coming from the engine bay. Sjo the items that has been: replaced: cylinder head, lifters (& bled), Gasket Kit, in and outlet valves, cam-belt, pistons, Oil rings and compression, crank bearings, Oil and petrol filter cleaned decently...

Comment: Is the sound of playing cards relative to RPM's?

Comment: Sure its safe to say yes to your question DucatiKiller... Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your engine have a timing chain or a belt?

Comment: Timing belt - its a 2010 Chev Corsa Utility 1.4.

Comment: Oh, important question - why was all of this replaced in the first place. Had the engine overheated?

Comment: ...Whole in the block, got a sub assembled and build that over..

Comment: Deck of cards sound? Might be a camshaft out of time. Sometimes an engine will run when the cam (or one cam) is off by a notch.

Comment: Check out http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22707/re-timing-my-engine-after-timing-belt-removal

Comment: If the cam 'holder' has a crack or rather a chip on the one side - is that a major issue? There's a ping noise from the cam as well.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "card in the spokes" noise sounds like an exhaust manifold leak. Since it didn't do it before the repair it would most likely be an exhaust manifold gasket leak, and not a hole in the manifold itself.

The white smoke could be antifreeze getting into the combustion chamber from a leaking head gasket. Here is a link to a question here about how to test for a leaking head gasket:  [How to test if head gaskets are blown?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17378/how-to-test-if-head-gaskets-are-blown/17396#17396)

I hope that helps!